# using XPath to select contiguous elements with a certain attribute value

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xpath-1.0

I have XML like this:

```
<span>1</span>
<span class="x">2</span>
<span class="x y">3</span>
<span class="x">4</span>
<span>5</span>
<span class="x">6</span>
<span>7</span>
<span class="x">8</span>
```

What I want is to use an XSLT stylesheet to put the contents of all elements whose `class` attribute contains `x` into one `<x>` element. So the output should be like this:

```
1 <x>234</x> 5 <x>6</x> 7 <x>8</x>
```

(or, ideally,

```
1 <x>2<y>3</y>4</x> 5 <x>6</x> 7 <x>8</x>
```

but that's a problem to tackle when I've solved this one.)

This is the relevant fragment of my XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="span[contains(@class,'x') and preceding-sibling::span[1][not(contains(@class,'x'))]]">
  <x><xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::span[contains(@class,'x')]">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
  </xsl:for-each></x>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span[contains(@class,'x') and preceding-sibling::span[1][contains(@class,'x')]]">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span">
  <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

What this produces is:

```
1 <x>23468</x> 5 <x>68</x> 7 <x>8</x>
```

I'm pretty sure I have to use a count in the XPath expression so that it doesn't select all of the following elements with class x, just the contiguous ones. But how can I count the contiguous ones? Or am I doing this the wrong way?

Comment: Please also post your `<xsl:call-template name="text">`.

Comment: I simplified my sample XSLT so that it doesn't call that template anymore. See edit.

Comment: Yeah, yet I was still interested in that template. It seemed unnecessary to me. :)

Comment: That template converts strings like `text [bracketed text] text` to `text <bracket>bracketed text</bracket> text`.

Comment: What about `<span>1</span><span class="x y">2</span><span class="y">3</span>`? Are both `1 <x><y>2</y></x><y>2</y>` and `1 <y><x>2</x>3</y>` good?

Comment: @ptomato This sounds like the ideal job for an `<xsl:template match="*" mode="text">`. This way you could throw out the `<xsl:for-each>` and the `<xsl:call-template>` and use `<xsl:apply-templates>` directly. This should save you quite a bit of code.

Comment: @MizardX, in the documents I'm transforming `y` won't occur without `x`, so I'd say the first option is sufficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is tricky, but doable (long read ahead, sorry for that).

The key to "consecutiveness" in terms of XPath axes (which are by definition not consecutive) is to check whether the closest node in the *opposite direction* that "first fulfills the condition" also is the one that "started" the series at hand:

```
a
b  <- first node to fulfill the condition, starts series 1
b  <- series 1
b  <- series 1
a
b  <- first node to fulfill the condition, starts series 2
b  <- series 2
b  <- series 2
a
```

In your case, a series consists of `<span>` nodes that have the string `x` in their `@class`:

```
span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' x ')]
```

<sup>*Note that I concat spaces to avoid false positives.*</sup>

A `<span>` that starts a series (i.e. one that "first fulfills the condition") can be defined as one that has an `x` in its class and is not directly preceded by another `<span>` that also has an `x`:

```
not(preceding-sibling::span[1][contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' x ')])
```

We must check this condition in an `<xsl:if>` to avoid that the template generates output for nodes that are in a series (i.e., the template will do actual work only for "starter nodes").

Now to the tricky part.

From each of these "starter nodes" we must select all `following-sibling::span` nodes that have an `x` in their class. Also include the current `span` to account for series that only have one element. Okay, easy enough:

```
. | following-sibling::span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' x ')]
```

For each of these we now find out if *their* closest "starter node" is identical to the one that the template is working on (i.e. that started *their* series). This means:

- they must be part of a series (i.e. they must follow a `span` with an `x`)

  ```
  preceding-sibling::span[1][contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' x ')]
  ```
- now remove any `span` whose starter node is not identical to the *current* series starter. That means we check any preceding-sibling `span` (that has an `x`) which itself is not directly preceded by a `span` with an `x`:

  ```
  preceding-sibling::span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' x ')][
    not(preceding-sibling::span[1][contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' x ')])
  ][1]
  ```
- Then we use `generate-id()` to check node identity. If the found node is identical to `$starter`, then the current span is one that belongs to the consecutive series.

Putting it all together:

```
<xsl:template match="span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' x ')]">
  <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::span[1][contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' x ')])">
    <xsl:variable name="starter" select="." />
    <x>
      <xsl:for-each select="
        . | following-sibling::span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' x ')][
          preceding-sibling::span[1][contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' x ')]
          and
          generate-id($starter)
          =
          generate-id(
            preceding-sibling::span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' x ')][
              not(preceding-sibling::span[1][contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' x ')])
            ][1]
          )
        ]
      ">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </x>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And yes, I know it's not pretty. There is an `<xsl:key>` based solution that is more efficient, Dimitre's answer shows it.

With your sample input, this output is generated:

```
1
<x>234</x>
5
<x>6</x>
7
<x>8</x>
```

Comment: But you need to think about the "ideally" problem, too :)

Comment: @Dimitre I thought about it and decided that it would not at all be a funny thing to implement (given that `class="w x y z"` would mean I'd have to implement a stack and a tokenizer and error-handling for mis-nested elements). I'm not even sure if my solution here is ideal (assuming a key should not be used).

Comment: Tomalak, no solution is "ideal" -- good, working solutions suffice.

Comment: @Dimitre As long as you attest that my logic/code does not contain blunder and cannot be simplified, it's okay with me. It seems a bit repetitive, but as far as I can see, every predicate is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

**I. XSLT Solutions**:

> What I want is to use an XSLT stylesheet to put the contents of all
>   elements whose class attribute contains `x` into one `<x>` element. So
>   the output should be like this:
>
> ```
> 1 <x>234</x> 5 <x>6</x> 7 <x>8</x>
> ```

**This transformation**:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match=
  "span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),
                 ' x ')
        ]"
   use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::span
                                    [not(contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),
                                             ' x '))
                                    ][1]
                    )
        "/>

 <xsl:template match=
 "span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' x ')
     and
       not(contains(concat(' ', preceding-sibling::span[1]/@class, ' '),
                    ' x '
                    )
           )
      ]"
  >
     <x>
       <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup" select=
       "key('kFollowing',
             generate-id(preceding-sibling::span                                                           [not(contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),                                                       ' x ')
                                 )
                            ][1]
                        )
            )
      "/>
     </x>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' x ')
     and
       contains(concat(' ', preceding-sibling::span[1]/@class, ' '),
                    ' x '
                    )
      ]
  "/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (wrapped into a single top element `html` to be made well-formed):

```
<html>
    <span>1</span>
    <span class="x">2</span>
    <span class="x y">3</span>
    <span class="x">4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span class="x">6</span>
    <span>7</span>
    <span class="x">8</span>
</html>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
1<x>234</x>5<x>6</x>7<x>8</x>
```

**Then the "ideally" addition**:

> or, ideally,
>
> ```
> 1 <x>2<y>3</y>4</x> 5 <x>6</x> 7 <x>8</x>
> ```
>
> but that's a problem to tackle when I've solved this one.)

**Just add to the above solution this template**:

```
  <xsl:template mode="inGroup" match=
    "span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),
                   ' y '
                   )
         ]">
    <y><xsl:value-of select="."/></y>
  </xsl:template>
```

**When applying the so modified solution to the same XML document, again the (new) wanted result is produced**:

```
1<x>2<y>3</y>4</x>5<x>6</x>7<x>8</x>
```

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 Solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:my="my:my" exclude-result-prefixes="my xs"
>
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
         <xsl:for-each-group select="span" group-adjacent=
          "contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' x ')">

           <xsl:sequence select=
           "if(current-grouping-key())
              then
                my:formatGroup(current-group())
              else
                data(current-group())
           "/>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:formatGroup" as="node()*">
  <xsl:param name="pGroup" as="node()*"/>

  <x>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$pGroup"/>
  </x>
 </xsl:function>

 <xsl:template match=
   "span[contains(concat(' ',@class, ' '), ' y ')]">
  <y><xsl:apply-templates/></y>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this XSLT 2.0 transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the wanted "ideal" result is produced**:

```
1<x>2<y>3</y>4</x>5<x>6</x>7<x>8</x>
```

Comment: @Tomalak, as usual, the XSLT 2.0 solution is much easier.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the solutions. In the meantime I've managed to put together something using a completely different tactic. I'm just learning XSLT for this project and the most helpful thing I've read is that XSLT is like functional programming. So I wrote something using recursion, after being pointed in the right direction by [this](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1604222):

```
<xsl:template match="span[
                       contains(@class,'x')
                       and
                       preceding-sibling::span[1][
                         not(contains(@class,'x'))
                       ]
                     ]">
  <x><xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="continue">
      <xsl:with-param name="next" select="following-sibling::span[1]"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </x>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="continue">
  <xsl:param name="next"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$next[contains(@class,'x')]">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="x" select="$next"/>
      <xsl:call-template name="continue">
        <xsl:with-param name="next" select="$next/following-sibling::span[1]"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise/><!-- Do nothing -->
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span[
                       contains(@class,'x')
                       and
                       preceding-sibling::span[1][
                         contains(@class,'x')
                       ]
                     ]"/>

<xsl:template match="span">
  <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="x" match="span[contains(@class,'y')]">
  <y><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></y>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="x" match="span">
  <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I have no idea whether this is more or less efficient than doing it with `generate-id()` or keys, but I certainly learned something from your solutions!

Comment: ptomato: There is nothing bad with a recursive solution, except that with large enough input the recursion often (unless specially coded using DVC or tail-recursion -- the latter not recognized by all XSLT processors) results in stack overflow and/or generally less than optimal efficiency.